# Transforming ARFrame#capturedImage to view size

Tags: ios, arkit

When using the `ARSessionDelegate` to process the raw camera image in ARKit...

```swift
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {

    guard let currentFrame = session.currentFrame else { return }
    let capturedImage = currentFrame.capturedImage

    debugPrint("Display size", UIScreen.main.bounds.size)
    debugPrint("Camera frame resolution", CVPixelBufferGetWidth(capturedImage), CVPixelBufferGetHeight(capturedImage))

    // ...

}
```

... as documented, the camera image data doesn't match the screen size, for example, on iPhone X I get:

- Display size: 375x812pt
- Camera resolution: 1920x1440px

Now there is the [displayTransform(for:viewportSize:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arframe/2923543-displaytransform) API to transform camera coordinates to view coordinates. When using the API like this:

```swift
let ciimage = CIImage(cvImageBuffer: capturedImage)
let transform = currentFrame.displayTransform(for: .portrait, viewportSize: UIScreen.main.bounds.size)
var transformedImage = ciimage.transformed(by: transform)
debugPrint("Transformed size", transformedImage.extent.size)
```

I get a size of 2340x1920 which seems incorrect, the result should have an aspect ratio of 375:812 (~0.46). What do I miss here / what's the correct way to use this API to transform the camera image to an image "as displayed by ARSCNView"?

(Example project: [ARKitCameraImage](https://github.com/ralfebert/ARKitCameraImage))

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This turned out to be quite complicated because `displayTransform(for:viewportSize)` expects normalized image coordinates, it seems you have to flip the coordinates only in portrait mode and the image needs to be not only transformed but also cropped. The following code does the trick for me. Suggestions how to improve this would be appreciated.

```swift
guard let frame = session.currentFrame else { return }
let imageBuffer = frame.capturedImage

let imageSize = CGSize(width: CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer), height: CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer))
let viewPort = sceneView.bounds
let viewPortSize = sceneView.bounds.size

let interfaceOrientation : UIInterfaceOrientation
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    interfaceOrientation = self.sceneView.window!.windowScene!.interfaceOrientation
} else {
    interfaceOrientation = UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation
}

let image = CIImage(cvImageBuffer: imageBuffer)

// The camera image doesn't match the view rotation and aspect ratio
// Transform the image:

// 1) Convert to "normalized image coordinates"
let normalizeTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0/imageSize.width, y: 1.0/imageSize.height)

// 2) Flip the Y axis (for some mysterious reason this is only necessary in portrait mode)
let flipTransform = (interfaceOrientation.isPortrait) ? CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: -1).translatedBy(x: -1, y: -1) : .identity

// 3) Apply the transformation provided by ARFrame
// This transformation converts:
// - From Normalized image coordinates (Normalized image coordinates range from (0,0) in the upper left corner of the image to (1,1) in the lower right corner)
// - To view coordinates ("a coordinate space appropriate for rendering the camera image onscreen")
// See also: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arframe/2923543-displaytransform

let displayTransform = frame.displayTransform(for: interfaceOrientation, viewportSize: viewPortSize)

// 4) Convert to view size
let toViewPortTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: viewPortSize.width, y: viewPortSize.height)

// Transform the image and crop it to the viewport
let transformedImage = image.transformed(by: normalizeTransform.concatenating(flipTransform).concatenating(displayTransform).concatenating(toViewPortTransform)).cropped(to: viewPort)
```

Comment: Here is a standalone example project making use of this code for a Metal shader that uses the camera image as displayed: https://github.com/ralfebert/ARSCNViewShaderExample .

Comment: I tried several other ways, this was the only one that made the ARFrame the same size and orientation as the image returned by snapshot() so they can be overplayed or  compared.

Comment: For me, the second part 2) did not work. Instead I skipped this part and applied `image = image.oriented(.upMirrored)` after the `.transformed` operation. I also had to multiply the width and heights by 3 to get the device resolution: `viewPort.size.width *= 3; viewPort.size.height *= 3; viewPortSize.width *= 3; viewPortSize.height *= 3`. I am using an iPhone 12 Pro.

Comment: This answer is awesome, it contains all steps explained to obtain the correct result. You can convert the final transformedImage to `UIImage` with `UIImage(ciImage: transformedImage)` and you can see in real time your results.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you so much for your answer! I was working on this for a week.

Here's an alternative way to do it without messing with the orientation. Instead of using the capturedImage property you can use a snapshot of the screen.

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
  guard let image = CIImage(image: sceneView.snapshot()) else { return }

  let imageSize = image.extent.size

  // Convert to "normalized image coordinates"
  let resize = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0 / imageSize.width, y: 1.0 / imageSize.height)

  // Convert to view size
  let viewSize = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: sceneView.bounds.size.width, y: sceneView.bounds.size.height)

  // Transform image
  let editedImage = image.transformed(by: resize.concatenating(viewSize)).cropped(to: sceneView.bounds)

  sceneView.scene.background.contents = context.createCGImage(editedImage, from: editedImage.extent)
 }
```

Comment: The question is not about choosing a method to copy the image pixels. But to use the capturedImage bits, as that last method does not copy bytes and achieve 60fps when used to overlay things.

Answer (score 0):

I've converted the awesome [Ralf Ebert answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58817480/1894067) to a swift extension:

But first, we need orientation:

```
extension UIApplication {
    var keyWindow: UIWindow? {
        return self.connectedScenes
            .filter { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive }
            .first(where: { $0 is UIWindowScene })
            .flatMap({ $0 as? UIWindowScene })?.windows
            .first(where: \.isKeyWindow)
    }
}

extension ARSession {
    func resizeTo(_ size:CGSize)->CIImage?{
        guard let frame = self.currentFrame else { return nil }
        let imageBuffer = frame.capturedImage
        let imageSize = CGSize(width: CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer), height: CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer))
        let interfaceOrientation = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.windowScene!.interfaceOrientation ?? .portrait
        let image = CIImage(cvImageBuffer: imageBuffer)
        let normalizeTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0/imageSize.width, y: 1.0/imageSize.height)
        let flipTransform = interfaceOrientation.isPortrait ? CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: -1).translatedBy(x: -1, y: -1) : .identity
        let viewPort = CGRect.init(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size)
        let displayTransform = frame.displayTransform(for: interfaceOrientation, viewportSize: size)
        let toViewPortTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: size.width, y: size.height)
        return image.transformed(by: normalizeTransform.concatenating(flipTransform).concatenating(displayTransform).concatenating(toViewPortTransform)).cropped(to: viewPort)
    }
}
```

---

**Usage:**

```
let resizedCIImage = myARSession.resizeTo(CGSize(width:300,height:300))
```